# Date of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, python-datetime

My data frame contains a IGN_DATE column in which the values are of the form 20080727142700,  format is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.
The column type is float64.

How can I get the a separate column for time, date (without 00:00:00), day, month.

What I tried:

Column name `IGN_DATE`
dataframe - df

```
df['IGN_DATE'] = df['IGN_DATE'].apply(str)

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['IGN_DATE'].str.slice(start = 0, stop = 8))
df['MONTH'] = df['IGN_DATE'].str.slice(start = 4, stop = 6).astype(int)
df['DAY'] = df['IGN_DATE'].str.slice(start = 6, stop = 8).astype(int)
df['TIME'] = df['IGN_DATE'].str.slice(start = 8, stop = 13)
```

1. DATE is in the format YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00. I don't want 00:00:00 in DATE.
2. How to get the time--which has type string--to HH:MM:SS ?
3. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `nan` values are not important can [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) then convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with a specified format then use the [`dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) to access desired values:

```
# Drop Rows with nan in IGN_DATE column
df = df.dropna(subset=['IGN_DATE'])
# Convert dtype to whole number then to `str`
df['IGN_DATE'] = df['IGN_DATE'].astype('int64').astype(str)
# Series of datetime values from Column
s = pd.to_datetime(df['IGN_DATE'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
# Extract out and add to DataFrame from `s`
df['DATE'] = s.dt.date
df['MONTH'] = s.dt.month
df['DAY'] = s.dt.day
df['TIME'] = s.dt.time
```

Otherwise can mask [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) values from `IGN_DATE` and assign only those rows:

```
# Mask not null values
m = df['IGN_DATE'].notna()
# Convert to String
df.loc[m, 'IGN_DATE'] = df.loc[m, 'IGN_DATE'].astype('int64').astype(str)
# Series of datetime values from Column
s = pd.to_datetime(df['IGN_DATE'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
# Extract out and add to DataFrame from `s`
df.loc[m, 'DATE'] = s.dt.date
df.loc[m, 'MONTH'] = s.dt.month
df.loc[m, 'DAY'] = s.dt.day
df.loc[m, 'TIME'] = s.dt.time
```

---

Sample DF:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'IGN_DATE': [20080727142700, np.nan, 20151015171807]})
```

Sample Output  with `dropna`:

```
         IGN_DATE        DATE  MONTH  DAY      TIME
0  20080727142700  2008-07-27      7   27  14:27:00
2  20151015171807  2015-10-15     10   15  17:18:07
```

Sample Output with mask:

```
         IGN_DATE        DATE  MONTH   DAY      TIME
0  20080727142700  2008-07-27    7.0  27.0  14:27:00
1             NaN         NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
2  20151015171807  2015-10-15   10.0  15.0  17:18:07
```

Comment: When I convert the data into string it changes 20080727142700 to 20080727142700.0 . So I used `mask = pd.to_numeric(df['IGN_DATE']).notnull()
df['IGN_DATE'].loc[mask] = df['IGN_DATE'].loc[mask].astype(np.int64)`, before I convert to string. But, I got warning:  SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Comment: Also, my data has two values of form  YYYYMMDDHHMMSS and YYYYMMDD. I am using for loop : `for row in df.columns:
    if (row['IGN_DATE'] > 1000000000):  `  But this if statement is not working. I even tried using `if ( row['IGN_DATE'].str.len() > 10)`.  I get error related to if statement. Any idea how to deal with this situation.

Comment: Sounds like you have `NaN` values in the column which makes the datatype `float` not int.  I've updated my answer to include handling this case. However the how to handle multiple different format types actually sounds like a [_new_ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about how to parse a column with multiple different date formats.

Comment: You are correct. It did had nan values which I removed in the starting using this`df.dropna(subset = ["IGN_DATE"], inplace=True)`. Thank you I will ask a new question.